# C++ HTTP 2 POST request getting rejected

Tags: rest, http, curl, post, http-post

I am trying to simulate this Curl command but only using C++:

```
curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: dummy_one" -X POST 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?hello'
```

The above request generates this response:

```
{"code":-2014,"msg":"API-key format invalid."}
```

Curl's verbose logging switch shows it sent this:

```
> POST /api/v3/order?hello HTTP/2
> Host: api.binance.com
> user-agent: curl/7.81.0
> accept: */*
> x-mbx-apikey: dummy_one
>
```

This is my attempt in C++:

```
char* write_buf = "POST /api/v3/order HTTP/2\r\n"
                  "Host: api.binance.com\r\n"
                  "user-agent: curl/7.81.0\r\n"
                  "accept: */*\r\n"
                  "X-MBX-APIKEY: dummy_one\r\n"
                  "content-length: 5\r\n"
                  "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                  "hello";

if(BIO_write(bio, write_buf, strlen(write_buf)) <= 0)
{
```

However, my request is getting rejected with:

`HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported`

After Googling I think this could be a generic error response, particularly with un-escaped spaces.

I'm not sure what is the exact problem.

My SSL connection is fine, it works perfectly with a GET request. The problem appears to be in the format of the POST request message.

Comment: @Evert The reason I set HTTP to version 2 is because the Curl verbose logging switch output this. I have added the Curl verbose output to the question.

Comment: I addressed this in my answer. CURL does send that data, but it's not the raw HTTP/2 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is HTTP/1.1. HTTP/2 is a binary protocol. Just change your `/2` to `/1.1` and you should get unstuck. HTTP/1.1 is not deprecated.

Curl verbose logging doesn't show the wire protocol, but rather just what it semantically sent.

Comment: Curl reports the server is okay to use version http 2 though?

Comment: @bicoi77 yes but you are not implementing the HTTP/2 protocol. HTTP/2 is a binary protocol. You are using HTTP/1.1 but using the incorrect version number for that protocol.

Comment: If I change it to version 1.1  I don't receive any response, the code just blocks on `bio_read()`

Comment: @bicoi77 well congrats you made it further ;) now you gotta solve your next problem. For sure add a `Connection: close` header while you're testing. I think you're also missing a newline between the headers and body.

Comment: @Thank you so much for the advice. I will try those suggestions and if i still get no response to work with, i'll post a new question later.

Comment: That worked! I get a large error response and it seems they are setting `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` to compliment the application error in the json `invalid API key`. Thank you so much.